# Can Vue break the button functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, forms, vuejs2

I have a jquery/ BS4 template. When  I add Vue for flashing message it broke my delete button functionality. The button has basic html form. But when I import the vue, delete button and checkboxes stop to working.

I think it is related with using the same id for **both vue and jquery** ? The html is too long so I will only add related part.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ $product->path() }}">
   @csrf
 {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
  <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn delete btn-sm"><i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i></button></td>
</form>
```

vue :

```
Vue.component('flash', require('./components/Flash.vue'));
 const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
 });
```

Comment: are there errors in the browser's console?

Comment: There is a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined" error. I handle the button click issue with wrapping component a specific id. But checkbox and some other jquery functioalities are gone. Here what I did : 

<div id="flash">
       <flash message="{{session('flash')}}"></flash>
     </div>

And "el: #flash"